# onChange in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to update the status of my `customerContact` with `handleChange`.
Indeed, I use the `updateContact` function to retrieve the customer's id to be able to modify their contact.
However, when I get the id I feel like I am blocking the status update.
So I can't edit a field in contact.

Can somebody help me, please?

```
class DetailsCustomer extends React.Component{

    constructor (props) {
   
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.toggle1 = this.toggle1.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            id: props.match.params,
            customers: [],
            customerContact: {},
            customerContacts: [],
            customerAddresses: [],
            genders: [],
            contactTypes: [],
            addressTypes: [],
        };
    }

  updateContact = (id, index) => {
        this.setState({
            customerContact: this.state.customerContacts[index],
        }, () => {
            console.log("update-contact: ", this.state.customerContact);
   })

  handleChange = async ({currentTarget}) => {
         const {name, value} = currentTarget;
         this.setState({...this.customerContact, [name]: value});
     }
  
render() {
const { id, customerContacts, customerContact, genders, name } = this.state;
   return(
         <div className="form-group col-md-12">
           <Field name="lastName" label="Nom" placeholder="Nom" value= 
            {this.state.customerContact.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
         </div>
)}
```

Field.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Field = ({name, label, value, onChange, placeholder = "", type = "text", error = "" }) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            type={type}
            placeholder={placeholder || label}
            name={name}
            id={name}
            className={"form-control" + (error && " is-invalid")}
        />
        {error && <p className="invalid-feedback">{error}</p> }
    </div>
);

export default Field;
```

Comment: why `handleChange ` is `async` when you're not performing any async operation

Comment: Oh it's a habit that I took, I'm recent in React. I am going to remove it

Comment: where did you get <Field/> component from ?

Comment: it's a component that I created, I just added it on my post

Comment: You doesn't need to bind handleChange, you are declaring it using an arrow function so it is already bind to the component class.

Comment: I tried with an arrow function but nothing changes, I still can’t change the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some syntax issue in your code like curly bracket missing of `updateContact` and your component `DetailsCustomer`

Secondly, there are two `bind` functions in your constructor `this.toggle` and `this.toggle1` which are not declared in your code, they are sending exceptions.

The last issue is in your `handleChange` function was assigning new value to `customerContact`

I made all correct in below code.

```
class DetailsCustomer extends React.Component{
    constructor (props) {
   
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            id: props.match.params,
            customers: [],
            customerContact: {},
            customerContacts: [],
            customerAddresses: [],
            genders: [],
            contactTypes: [],
            addressTypes: [],
        };
    }

  updateContact = (id, index) => {
    this.setState({
        customerContact: this.state.customerContacts[index],
    }, () => {
        console.log("update-contact: ", this.state.customerContact);
    })
  }

  handleChange = ({currentTarget}) => {
    const {name, value} = currentTarget;
    this.setState({customerContact: {...this.state.customerContact, [name]: value}}, () => console.log(this.state.customerContact));
  }
  
  render() {
    const { id, customerContacts, customerContact, genders, name } = this.state;
      return(
            <div className="form-group col-md-12">
              <Field name="lastName" label="Nom" placeholder="Nom" value= 
                {this.state.customerContact.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer it worked very well :) ! this.toggle and this.toggle1 are well stated in my code, but I did not deem it useful to post them, again thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you say that handleChange need to get a object but you dont give it when you call handleChange. i think this may help.
if you use arrow function => you dont need to use this.bind on functions

```
class DetailsCustomer extends React.Component{

    constructor (props) {
   
        super(props)       
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.toggle1 = this.toggle1.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            id: props.match.params,
            customers: [],
            customerContact: {},
            customerContacts: [],
            customerAddresses: [],
            genders: [],
            contactTypes: [],
            addressTypes: [],
        };
    }

  updateContact = (id, index) => {
        this.setState({
            customerContact: this.state.customerContacts[index],
        }, () => {
            console.log("update-contact: ", this.state.customerContact);
   })

  handleChange = async (e) => {         
         this.setState({customerContact: e.target.value});
     }
  
render() {
const { id, customerContacts, customerContact, genders, name } = this.state;
   return(
         <div className="form-group col-md-12">
           <Field name="lastName" label="Nom" placeholder="Nom" value= 
            {this.state.customerContact} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)} />
         </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I tried with what you told me nothing changes, I still can’t change the fields

Comment: @Marine i did update. now you should be able to get the user input onChange. i dont  understand why you use: const { id, customerContacts, customerContact, genders, name } = this.state;

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it worked well :)! I don’t post all my code, but this allows me to use what I declare in my constructor